# How to constrain associated type synonyms?

Tags: haskell, type-families, abstract-algebra

I'm (relatively) new to Haskell and want to code some math. For example, abelian groups. I would like to write the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

module Structures where

class Eq g => AbelianGroup g where
    type family AbelianGroupElement g = e | e -> g
    add :: AbelianGroupElement g -> AbelianGroupElement g -> AbelianGroupElement g
    inv :: AbelianGroupElement g -> AbelianGroupElement g
    unit :: g -> AbelianGroupElement g
    parent :: AbelianGroupElement g -> g

data Z = Z deriving Eq
data ZElement = ZElement Z Int deriving Eq

instance AbelianGroup Z where
    type instance AbelianGroupElement Z = ZElement
    add (ZElement z1 x1) (ZElement z2 x2)
        | z1 == z2 = (ZElement z1 (x1+x2))
        | otherwise = error "elements from different groups"
    inv (ZElement z x) = (ZElement z (-x))
    unit z = ZElement z 0
    parent (ZElement z x) = z

data ProductAbGrp g1 g2 = 
    ProductAbGrp g1 g2 deriving Eq
data ProductAbGrpEl g1 g2 = 
    ProductAbGrpEl (ProductAbGrp g1 g2) (AbelianGroupElement g1) (AbelianGroupElement g2) deriving Eq
```

Compiling the above gives me the error

```
No instance for (Eq (AbelianGroupElement g1))
        arising from the second field of `ProductAbGrpEl'
          (type `AbelianGroupElement g1')
```

This makes sense; I haven't ensured that (AbelianGroupElement g1) always has Eq defined for it. However, I'm not sure how I can accomplish that. I can change the above to

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-} 
...
class (Eq g, Eq (AbelianGroupElement g)) => AbelianGroup g where
```

but this doesn't help. (It's possible that type families are the wrong way to go here; I originally started with MultiParamTypeClasses and FunctionalDependencies, but had other issues with that and got the impression that type families were better).

Thanks for reading this; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you need multiparam-classes or fun-deps, etc. anyway? Look at `Num` - it includes basically everything you need without the need for advanced stuff?

Comment: in case you want/need this for different representations of the same type (*set* if you like) - you can always do this with `newtype`s of said type

Comment: Good question; I've seen lots of other implementations of algebraic structures in Haskell where they do what you suggested and create a typeclass for only elements of a structure. However, I would like to be able to work with the structures themselves, like forming sub-structures of things. e.g. I'd like to distinguish between 2 as an element of the integers and 2 as an element of the even integers.

Comment: Note that injectivity annotations (`.... | e -> g`) do not work as most people would expect them to. Injectivity is not exploited during type inference (in current GHC, at least) -- as if the annotation were not there. In particular, types like `add :: AbelianGroupElement g -> AbelianGroupElement g -> AbelianGroupElement g` are considered ambiguous, since the type does not mandate the use of any specific `g` (because of non-injectivity). Maybe you could consider `data family` instead, which are injective? (This might not be your actual problem, though.)

Comment: `data family` might help. I can replace `type family` with it in my code and I get to the same point. I feel like what I really want to is to be able to write `data family AbelianGroupElement g deriving Eq`, but ghc tells me this is nonsense. I could just add `deriving Eq` to every `data instance` I write, but Haskell doesn't know that there couldn't be more instances.

Comment: @chi, type family injectivity is used *only* for inference, just never for checking. Not sure what you meant there. But an injectivity annotation from the element to the group seems to make the distinction pretty useless; might as well just use the element type to represent the group in the conventional manner if you're going to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`StandaloneDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/standalone_deriving.html#extension-StandaloneDeriving) to get basically what you want, although I admit it's not as pretty as simply writing `deriving Eq`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance (Eq g1, Eq g2, Eq (AbelianGroupElement g1), Eq (AbelianGroupElement g2)) => Eq (ProductAbGrpEl g1 g2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to a MultiParamTypeClasses and FunctionalDependencies approach. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things, but it at least solves this issue. I had tried this previously, but didn't know that I could add both dependencies `e -> g` and `g -> e`, which made a difference as far as getting this code to compile.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}    

module Structures where
    
class (Eq g, Show g, Eq e, Show e) => AbelianGroup g e | e -> g, g -> e where
    zero :: g -> e
    add :: e -> e -> e
    neg :: e -> e
    parent :: e -> g

data Z = Z deriving (Eq, Show)
data ZElement = ZElement Z Int deriving (Eq, Show)

instance AbelianGroup Z ZElement where
    zero z = ZElement z 0
    add (ZElement z1 x1) (ZElement z2 x2)
        | z1 == z2 = (ZElement z1 (x1+x2))
        | otherwise = error "elements from different groups"
    neg (ZElement z x) = (ZElement z (-x))
    parent (ZElement z x) = z

data ProductAbelianGroup g1 g2 e1 e2 = ProductAbelianGroup g1 g2 deriving (Eq, Show)
data ProductAbelianGroupElement g1 g2 e1 e2 = ProductAbelianGroupElement g1 g2 e1 e2 deriving (Eq, Show)
```